# How to remove an account from Mail app in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-app, windows-8-mail-app

I added my Outlook mail account and Gmail account to the Mail app of Windows 8. Now I want want to remove one of those account from the app. How do I do that ? 
I searched every where but there if no option to that. Does any one know how to do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Activate the charm bar with <kbd>win</kbd> - <kbd>C</kbd>

Go to Settings then Accounts then Click on the account you want to delete, scroll *all* the way down on the accounts settings page, and click on the remove account button

[image]

Comment: I think its same as Win-XP & 7, am i right ?

Comment: Hmm, Windows XP and 7 didn't have a metro/modern ui mail app ;p

Comment: wow, this is really nice feature.

Comment: being able to remove accounts? I'd consider it *essential*

Comment: No, i mean its new look

Comment: Is there any other way to open that besides WIN-C? Just curious, as there should be a method with the mouse. Thanks for the solution, too.

Comment: you can swipe the right edge. I just find win-c to be so much easier